# Find the referring URL and parse it

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, url, referrer

Okay my problem is there are two websites with two different servers. What I'm trying to do is write some of the buttons for website 1, but on a page on my server (website 2).

So to do this the approach is

- User clicks on button from website 1.
- User is redirected to website 2.
- I need to know what page they came from so I know what product they are looking at. Which will be done by getting the referrer URL.
- I then need to parse the URL's productID's number.

example URL: website1.com/ProductDetails/?referrerPage=1&productID=#######&tab=Tile

I know that I need to use this piece of code to store the referrer URL in a string:

```
myReferrer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
```

I don't really know where to place it tho. I'm guessing in my .cs file where my button is?

```
protected void btnEstimate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection strings
    {
        does stuff
        {
            does stuff
        }
```

So my question is how do I get the referring URL, and then parse out the item ID?

Thanks for the help in advance. If anything is unclear please ask... this is my first time asking a question so I may be unclear. Thanks!

Comment: `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`.

Comment: You can do the following two i think of. 1. since the viewer is on site 1 pass some arguments to the link of site 2.  And 2, store the UrlReferrer on page load on site 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

[Making Sense of ASP.NET Paths](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths)

Note that a fully qualified URL including querystring and extra path is a Uri instance rather than string. You can use the UriBuilder.Query Property to extract the query string parameter(s):

You need to parse the URI in the Page_Load method of the receiving site's page.

[UriBuilder.Query Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.query.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There's a server variable called HTTP_REFERER. You can access it with `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`

It's misspelled, I know, but that's how you really need to call the server variable.

Your referrer server variable is only going to be populated if the user clicks on a link. AFAIK if you redirect, that variable is going to be empty.

[Wikipedia Referer Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer)